# Why do I keep getting an error on this short applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell security preferences
        get properties
    end tell
end tell
```

The script editor gives the error "System Events got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000

Comment: My guess is this is a bug. I'm sure this script used to work. It's an example from Apple (as I'm sure you knew). The Dictionary for System Events clearly shows properties. You can get properties of several other Preferences still, but no longer Security Preferences. You can still get the individual properties, so can just get them all individually directly to get around the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no `properties` property in `secure preferences object`.
The available properties are:

- `automatic login`
- `log out when inactive`
- `log out when inactive interval`
- `require password to unlock`
- `require password to wake`
- `secure virtual memory` (returns an error, seems to be a bug)

Read a property directly for example

```
tell application "System Events"
  tell security preferences
    get automatic login 
  end tell
end tell
```